# creating a formula string in VBA using part formula and part hard coded string

Tags: vba

```
Dim cell_range As range
Set cell_range = Worksheets("beans").range("T11")

Dim x As Integer
x = 0
Dim current_range As range
Set current_range = cell_range

Dim actual_test_range As String
Do
    actual_test_range = current_range.Offset(0, x).address
    current_range.Offset(0, x).Formula = "=if(" & current_range.Offset(0, x).address & "= "APPLES",1,0)"
    x = x + 1
Loop Until x = 60
```

The idea is that if the cell in current range = "APPLES" then return 1 else return 0

I cannot get this to work as VBA won't accept "APPLES" where it is currently located and I don't know how to construct a string for the formula out of variables and hard coded strings.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up the quotes when used within a quoted string (i.e. the formula) but it also looks like it might be a circular reference in that you are inserting a formula into a cell that references itself.

```
current_range.Offset(0, x).Formula = "=if(" & current_range.Offset(0, x).address & "= ""APPLES"",1,0)"
```